# How to handle NullPointerException when I need to know when an object points to null? java

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception

I am working on a Linked List class that acts exactly like the Java API List. I have a set of Nodes, each Node is an ArrayList that is set to hold a certain number of elements. I have to index all the objects in my lists in order, no matter where they sit in each in Node. So two objects can be separated by a null object. but the indexes would still be 1 then 2.

I keep getting a NullPointerException when I try to send back an object that has been set to Null. I need to know when an object is null so that I can skip over it. 
bucket is an ArrayList.

```
    private T checkObjectAtIndex(int i){
        T thing;
        try {
            thing = bucket.get(i);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
        }
        if(i>=bucket.size()){
            thing = null;
        }else if(bucket.get(i) != null){
        thing = bucket.get(i);
        }else{
            thing = null;
        }
        return thing;

    }
```

This is where I keep getting the NullPointerException, when I call this method. How do I handle this so that I can analyze objects that are pointed to null. Like if I check my list at a specific index and it's pointed to null I want to throw a fail in my test class not cause my code to crash. I tried another catch statement and it still crashed.

EDIT:
I updated the code to try and catch the NullPointerException. I am still getting it though and it is still causing my program to crash :(

```
        @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    private T checkObjectAtIndex(int i){
        T thing;
        try {
            thing = bucket.get(i);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
        } finally{
        if(i>=bucket.size()){
            return null;}
        else if(bucket.get(i) != null){
        thing = bucket.get(i);
        return thing;
        }else{
            return null;
            }

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Regarding catching: Java's implementations deliberately don't catch / even throw exceptions because they indicate wrong use of the class. You should not attempt to handle e.g. `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because now the guy that uses your list implementation has no chance to handle the error he caused.

Comment: My class is supposed to handle indexoutofbounds exceptions. That way, when I try to add things out of bounds in my test class it will tell me I can't, and then move on with the rest of my tests instead of ending. Or is that not the right way to catch it? I am still learning java.

Comment: "My class is supposed to handle indexoutofbounds exceptions" sounds wrong to me. That type of exception means that you did not make sure that your code can't violate the contract of a `List` (valid indexes are within `.size()`(-1) only). Those [unchecked exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) are usually meant to crash your program so the programmer knows that something is wrong. Edit: in case the program part here is the test for the class: yes catch all the things and check that you get the expected exception.

Comment: So instead of catching it should I use a "throws IndexOutOfBoundsExceotion"? and then try and just catch the NullPointerException?

Comment: Inside the list class catch nothing. Let it crash. As early as possible. Inside a test case class that is testing the functionality of you list feel free to catch exceptions if you e.g. verify that accessing your list implementation out of bounds throws an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @zapl How would I catch it in my test class? Do I just move the try/catch statement into the method testing it?

Comment: Yes. Similar to http://www.ensor.cc/2012/09/testing-custom-exceptions-w-junits.html (the old way)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(someThing != null){
    dothis;
}else{
    dothat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It still crashes because you're trying to catch an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` meanwhile the `NullPointerException` is not a subclass of it.

You can both check whether the `bucket` is null previously you try to use the `get()` method:

```
private T checkObjectAtIndex(int i){
    if(bucket == null) return null;
    ...
}
```

or you can catch NullPointerException:

```
    try {
        thing = bucket.get(i);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
    } finally {
        return null;
    }
```

I'd go with the first option, since NPE is an unchecked exception, so the try is not really necessary, and you can easily check if the object is null or not.

Comment: I tried adding in a second catch for the NullPointerException but it is  still stopping my program.

Comment: @user3053287 Does it print the stack trace in the console? Can you share with us?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MyLinkedList$Node.access$0(MyLinkedList.java:65)
 at MyLinkedList.get(MyLinkedList.java:197)
 at CrapTest.checkList(CrapTest.java:18)
 at CrapTest.main(CrapTest.java:40)

Comment: @user3053287 It doesn`t seem like the application is broken, it is just telling you that a NPE occurred, I believe your program still runs fine, am I right? If you don`t want to let the exception occur go with the first option I stated.

Comment: @user3053287 Hold on, your stack trace says that the NPE occurred in the `checkList` method, meanwhile the method you posted here is the `checkObjectAtIndex`

Comment: What happens is, I am adding 8 objects to my list. The I run a test. I have a control item that adds the same items to a list backed  by the Java API and then I run a method that compares our lists. For some reason my list throws a NullPointerException while checking the second object.

Comment: Yes my test class has a method called checklist() that compares the lists. The checklist method calls the get() method for a list of indexes. THe get() method calls checkObjectAtIndex() to search the arrayList for each node.

Comment: The NPE occur at line 18 of CrapTest, you sure you`re not looking at the wrong place? Please realize it and treat it appropriately.